# iOS and OS X: When does Base localization take precedence?

Tags: ios, macos, localization, internationalization, resources

Say you have a localized resource that is in en.lproj and Base.lproj.  If someone runs the app in, say, Spanish, is the Base.proj resource loaded over the en.lproj one?

Generally, what happens when an resource for the user's preferred language is not found, and when does the system fall back to Base resources?

Comment: if you have a localization for spanish, there should also be a es.lproj folder in with the en.lproj and Base

Answer (score 1):

Base is used whenever the translation for the user language is not define. Including if you have done 99% of string transition to "French", and you should display one of this 1% left on a French iPhone => the base will be use.

I like to have base = english. If a user did not have is natural language translated, he will se the english version.

Some people think different. We all have our reason ;-)
They said, use "code" for base, if you miss to translate you will see code instead of english. Easy to "debug" missing translation.
I said, if you miss to translate a string, the user will see the english version. He will probably said "Oh no ! again this english ! This soft is not well translate !". I already be in that situation 1000 times may be more. Nethertheless, I was able to translate the english sentence to my natural language... not sure to be able to translate a "code"...

Answer (score 0):

If none of your defined languages is not equal to the one which the user has its phone language, then the `Base` takes place.

Suppose you have 3 localizations, english, spanish and french, and of course you have your based localize. If french or spanish or english are not the phone language, then the base specified by you will be set.